# Adding titles under the thumbnails in my vimeo player using json and javascript and css

Tags: javascript, css, json

If i inspect element on my page i can see this code.

[image: No titles under the thumbnails]

```
<div id="player_carousel_wrap" style="width: 800px; height: 110px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 60px; top: 20px;">
```

[image: Vimeo with titles, how I would like to see it]

If i edit the height to `160px` or take out the `overflow: hidden;` i can get the titles.

The problem is that code above is not on the actual page/file, only when i inspect element. Presumably because it's json?

I have a vimeo carousel player that works fairly easy. You can view it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3hPAL/1296/

Using Json and javascript

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in the css: #player_carousel_wrap { height:160px !important }

Or modify the style using javascript after the vimeo player is initialized.

**The clean way:**

After looking through the plugin, setting the size higher than the thumbnail height should be the best way. http://jsfiddle.net/scottux/3hPAL/1298/

```
    'carousel': {
        size:160,
        offsetx: 60,
        offsety: 20,
        visible: 2,
        autoplay: true,  
        thumb:{
            quality:'large',
            height:120
        }
    }
```

```

Comment: Is that what !important does? Thanks it worked perfect.

Comment: !important overrides everything. Sometimes when content comes in and the style are inline, there is no other way to override it without using javascript and a timeout.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. Another quick question if you have a moment. I have 4 video's total and the carousel at the bottom is wide enough to fit all 4 video's without the need for the left and right arrows. How can i consolidate the carousel?

Comment: One of the carousel option properties should be 'visible', I think you have it set to 2 - setting it to 4 should work.

Comment: That worked, not sure how i missed that one. Thank you very much Scottux.